# Converting a derivative constraint into an orthogonality constraint

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let's say I'm trying to generate a quadratic curve in 3 dimensions, given two points it passes through, $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and normals to the curve at those points, $\vec n_1$ and $\vec n_2$.  My curve is parametrically defined in the form $r(t)= \vec a + (\vec b - \vec a - \vec c)t + \vec c t^2$, which automatically satisfies the positional constraints $r(0)=\vec a$ and $r(1)=\vec b$. In this case, my orthogonality constraints are easily described:

$$\vec n_1 \cdot {dr \over {dt}}(0) = 0; \quad \vec n_2 \cdot {dr \over {dt}}(1) = 0$$

Calculating $dr \over dt$ and grouping terms, I get a linear system of equations, which can be easily solved for the missing curvature parameter $\vec c$:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
\vec n_1^T \\
\vec n_2^T \\
\end{bmatrix} \vec c = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\vec n_1^T (\vec b - \vec a) \\
\vec n_2^T (\vec b - \vec a) \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

Following [this paper](http://cs.engr.uky.edu/~cheng/PUBL/Paper_Nagata.pdf), you get a simple analytical solution using the pseudo-inverse of the 2 x 3 matrix on the left.

Now, I'd like to extend this method to interpolate a function of the same form, but mapping to a higher dimension $F(t):\mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$.  This time, however, instead of normals to the curve, I have values of the derivative of the function at the endpoints, ${dF \over {dt}}(0)$ and ${dF \over {dt}}(1)$.  Using the derivatives as constraints directly requires finding the pseudo-inverse of a much larger matrix, or else switching to a cubic parameterization ([hermite spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline)), neither of which will work for my application.  How can I keep my constraints in the form of a simple dot-product?